# I get code while displaying terms and conditions in checkout onepage

Tags: cms, static-block, cms-block, render, template-directive

I created a terms and conditions page via `Sales > Terms and Conditions`, I created a terms page and content as 
`{{block type="cms/block" block_id="terms"}}`.

I also created static block from `CMS > Static Block` and created a page with identifier as test. But when I see the checkout review page, I get the same content `{{block type="cms/block" block_id="terms"}}` and not the real content which is placed in `CMS > Static Block`.

I tried with `{{block type="cms/block" block_id="terms" template="agreements/list.phtml"}}` But doesn't seem to work.

I believe there is some rendering problem. But not really sure. 
I tried googling around, I couldn't find a solution for this problem.

Comment: you have create terms page from cms>section

Comment: @AmitBera yes, I created terms page under CMS > static block. I am linking that block_id from Sales > terms and conditions

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
{{block type="checkout/agreements" name="checkout.onepage.all" as="agreementsaa" template="checkout/onepage/agreements.phtml"}}
```

Or goto your  `Admin >cms> page>` select your cms page and the  click on `Design tab>Layout Update XML` and put this code:

```
<reference name="content">
<block type="checkout/agreements" name="checkout.onepage.all" as="agreementsaa" template="checkout/onepage/agreements.phtml" />
</reference>
```

Comment: I updated the code in Design tab, But how can I link this terms page ? I tried both ways, It show plain code {{block type="checkout/agreements" name="checkout.onepage.all" as="agreementsaa" template="checkout/onepage/agreements.phtml"}} on the browser and doesn't show content.

Comment: you need to enable t&c setting from  `system>configuration>Sales>checkout>Checkout option`  and make `Enable Terms and Conditions` -`yes`

Comment: Yes, It is already yes. I am getting confused on where it went wrong. I copied the entire magento code from one place to another. This resulted this problem. Before it used to work well.

Comment: `Admin >cms> page>` select your cms page and the  click on `Design tab>Layout Update XML`   and put the code :`<reference name="content">
<block type="checkout/agreements" name="checkout.onepage.all" as="agreementsaa" template="checkout/onepage/agreements.phtml" />
</reference>`

Comment: it has working fine in my system

Comment: I updated Layout update XML, But how do you call this page ??? I in Sales ? Terms and conditions, we should call this reference right ?

Comment: you cannot call a page to checkout page... magento default  call the Terms and Conditions content in its  checkout  review step..Donot need ro create page from cms....

Comment: If you dont need a page how could you edit as suggested above :
Admin >cms> page> select your cms page and the click on Design tab>Layout Update XML
???

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 1.9.x it should be like

`<block type="checkout/agreements" name="checkout.onepage.agreements" as="agreements" template="checkout/onepage/agreements.phtml"/>'`

Comment: You mean that I should update this above <block type .. /> in Sales > Terms and Conditions > content section ? But, how should I specify block_id ? Since, I created page in CMS > Static block with block_id as terms.

Comment: Default template in 1.9.x is "checkout/onepage/agreements.phtml". Either you use {{block type="cms/block" block_id="terms" template="checkout/onepage/agreements.phtml"}} or {{block type="cms/block" block_id="terms" template="cms/widget/static_block/default.phtml"}}

Comment: I still get only {{block type="cms/block" block_id="terms" template="cms/widget/static_block/default.phtml"}} in the display.. not the actual content of terms.

Comment: Did you paste this code in WYSIWYG-Editor? If yes, then "hide editor", past code again and try again.

Comment: No, `Sales > Terms and Conditions` doesnt have WYSIWYG-Editor. I updated this `{{block type="cms/block" block_id="terms" template="checkout/onepage/agreements.phtml"}}` as a plain text. Earlier, This used to render .. But when I cloned the copy of entire magento code, the new copy has this rendering problem. Not sure what went wrong.

Comment: How do you solved this ? I still get this display :
http://i.imgur.com/ixbUqRb.png